# How to move or navigate from .mm file to .m file

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, objective-c++

I have little proble with .mm file. i have to navigate .mm file to .m file but i can't navigate .m file. any one knows how to move it.

Example:-

```
AlarmViewController *objAlarmViewController =[[AlarmViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"AlarmViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:objAlarmViewController animated:YES];
```

I am trying to do this code in .mm file but i can't move to .m file. 
& i got one error regarding uinavigationcontroller.**(error: Property 'navigationcontroller' not found on object of type 'ABCViewcontroller*')**

**Note:- I am not asking to change file extention .mm to .m file. i just want to navigate from .mm file to .m file.**

Comment: Check if your ABCViewcontroller is inside a navigation controller or not

Comment: This is not what i m ask you Mr. Abhi.

Answer (score 2):

You just fire a NSNotification from .mm file and handle that notification in .m
and put a observer in .m file

Comment: you can't under stand my question bro. @Rajan

Comment: i really cant understand..what are you tryng to do..navigation control is part of which class...??U have to call anything from .mm to .m or what?

Comment: just provide the entire code.. you are writing self.nav... self is pointing to current class where navigation is placed as a base container....

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html

Please Download below sample code.

Comment: which .mm file you are talking about

Comment: And this code you can see the "SpeakHereController.mm" file. In this file you can see "record" method. when ever i tap on record button then recording is working good but i can little change on code that when i tap on record button then it's move to another view which is (ABCViewcontroller.m).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74102/discussion-between-sandy-patel-and-rajan).

Comment: bro its a subclass of nsobject...how can you call a self.nav from it

Comment: no i can't give you + point. little prob with my account. but now it's fine. is it okey now?

Comment: i give you upvote on another question bro.. i can't upvote on this question.